# Why is my Button not correctly registering the output?

Tags: c#, button, unity-game-engine

I have the following code:

```
void Setup(CityBuilding[] buildings) {
    foreach (CityBuilding building in buildings)
    {
        GameObject buildingDisp = Instantiate(singleGoodsDisplay);
        //... Other stuff not relevent happens here
        buildingDisp.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => { ProcessClick(building); });
        Debug.Log(building);
    }
}

private void ProcessClick(CityBuilding building)
{
    Debug.Log(building);
}
```

The bottom line is, I have a few buttons that are saved as a prefab and instantiated. I'm adding an onClick Listener to it, in the form of a lambda function. I'm passing in a data object. Right now `buildings` is an array of two. I see that both items are debugged, however, when I actually click on the buttons, I always see the second item is used, never the first. I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if the behaviour is the same in C#, but if you had a similar thing in javascript, by the time the click happens, the local `building` will always refer to the last item in the collection.

Comment: Apparently it was changed in C# 5, so that the variable is consider "new" in each iteration, so disregard.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the object reference isn't saved, it only uses the latest. What does work is to save a copy and pass it, as follows:

```
void Setup(CityBuilding[] buildings) {
    foreach (CityBuilding building in buildings)
    {
        CityBuilding temp=building;
        GameObject buildingDisp = Instantiate(singleGoodsDisplay);
        //... Other stuff not relevent happens here
        buildingDisp.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => { ProcessClick(temp); });
    }
}
```

Comment: bizarre I've never seen this - but, great!